# What is meta- data and meta features?

Tags: classification, feature-selection, feature-extraction, clustering, metadata

I want to know what is metadata and what is meant by meta features?

When I google Meta Features what I get is feature selection tool called "Meta-Feature". What is the function of feature selection tools ?

Also, what I want is the definition and meaning of the meta features ?

Comment: Distinct dimensions of a very very large number of objects/persons are recorded across time/geography. It can be termed as metadata - wide spread. To summarize this, we explore the data to classify and use graphs to develop a general understanding of   the particular phenomenon. Certain statistical methods such as factor analysis or discriminent analysis  can help. Meta features or key traits reflect generalized latent factors - each being independent subset or covariate explaining one or more other variables.

Answer (score 2):

Gramatically "Meta" comes from greek and means beyond something. "Meta-Feature" means beyond the feature.

Normally refers to how the feature was obtained, the uncertainty, error measurements...
For example, in atmospheric modeling, for the features "Temperature" you can have a lot of different meta features like, with which tool are you measuring the temperature? what is the error of the tool? in which conditions is the measurement happening?

I understand the term meta feature as a generalization of this concept but in Data Science.